# SQL left outer join to find not in 3 tables

Tags: sql, join

I'd like to get a count of items not in 3 tables. The third table is in another database and should only be for producer_ID 139.
Run as this I get 859 as a count:

```
        SELECT count(item.item_ID) as itemcount 
        FROM   item
        LEFT OUTER JOIN item_Subject
          ON (item.item_ID = item_Subject.item_ID)          

        LEFT OUTER JOIN item_Category
          ON (item.item_ID = item_Category.item_ID)

        LEFT OUTER JOIN DATABASE2.dbo.item_SuperCategory
          ON (item.item_ID = DATABASE2.dbo.item_SuperCategory.item_ID 
               and  DATABASE2.dbo.item_SuperCategory.Producer_ID = 139)  

          WHERE item_Category.item_ID IS NULL
          and item_Subject.item_ID IS NULL  
          and DATABASE2.dbo.item_SuperCategory.item_ID IS NULL
```

But if I take out the **DATABASE2.dbo.item_SuperCategory.Producer_ID = 139** and run I get only 23.  I expected the number to be reduced, not increased.  What is wrong?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question, if you get 859 before and 23 after it has reduced so nothing is wrong.

Comment: I mean with the condition of Producer_ID=139 I would expect fewer.  With the condition there are 859, without the condition there are only 23.

Comment: I need a count of items not found in any of these 3 tables.

Answer (score 0):

This query counts items which have null itemID. The fact that you get 23 as opposed to 859 after removing the producer_id = 139 means that items with a producer_id of 139 account for 836 of your items in the DATABASE2.dbo.item_SuperCategory table.

Remember that you're searching for null values in a left-joined table, so to further filter that table alone in the join clause can only increase nulls.